# Confusion about Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) example

Tags: java, sorting, collections, generic-collections

Here is the code

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>, Comparable<Dog> {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    Dog() {
    }

    Dog(String n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    public String getDogName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDogAge() {
        return age;
    }

    // Overriding the compareTo method
    public int compareTo(Dog d) {
        return (this.name).compareTo(d.name);
    }

    // Overriding the compare method to sort the age
    public int compare(Dog d, Dog d1) {
        return d.age - d1.age;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Takes a list o Dog objects
        List<Dog> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();

        list.add(new Dog("Shaggy", 3));
        list.add(new Dog("Lacy", 2));
        list.add(new Dog("Roger", 10));
        list.add(new Dog("Tommy", 4));
        list.add(new Dog("Tammy", 1));
        Collections.sort(list);// Sorts the array list

        for (Dog a : list)
            // printing the sorted list of names
            System.out.print(a.getDogName() + ", ");

        // Sorts the array list using comparator
        Collections.sort(list, new Dog());
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (Dog a : list)
            // printing the sorted list of ages
            System.out.print(a.getDogName() + "  : " + a.getDogAge() + ", ");
    }
}
```

I know that the 2-argument sort method here takes the arguments of type List and a Comparator. But here when we pass the list Dog and a new Object of Dog, I just don't understand what is happening in the compare() method? i.e.

```
return d1.age - d2.age;
```

What does this signify? And if I do

```
return d1.age + d2.age;
```

why does it change the ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `d1.age - d2.age`

- if negative number, then d1 is logically less than d2 in sort order
- if positive, then d1 is logically greather than d2 in sort order
- if 0, then objects are equal

You can refer the [javadoc for compare method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T))

So when you are sorting dogs, and your compare method is comparing their ages, hence **Tammy** is less than **Lacy** according to the your method implementation.

Making Dog implement both `Comparable` and `Comparator` seems like a bad idea to me.

- `Collections.sort(list)` will cause `compareTo()` method to be
  invoked
- `Collections.sort(list, new Dog())` will cause `compare()` method to be invoked

I believe you should look into sorting user defined object using [Comparable](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-1/) and [Comparator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/)

Comment: specifically I wanted to ask what value does d2.age signify here?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. d2.age simply specifies the age of dog that is being compared with d1

Answer (score 3):

A good practice is to write such [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) methods using [Integer.compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) method:

```
public int compare(Dog d, Dog d1) {
  return Integer.compare(d.age, d1.age);
}
```

I think, this way it is much more obvious, what is going on here.
(Also, this way is safer.)

Comment: Yes. It's safer, because the typical comparison using subtraction `d.age - d1.age` might give the wrong result because of integer overflow. This is unlikely with typical dog ages :-) but it could happen with other values.

Comment: @StuartMarks Yes, sure, you are right :-) But I consider it as a good habit - if you do it, then do it everywhere. An another gain is that you need not to remember, when to return 0, 1, or -1. Should it be `d.age - d1.age`? Or `d1.age - d.age`? `Integer.compare(d.age, d1.age)` is much less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Your class (Dog) implements both `Comparator` and `Comparable` interfaces.
We can say that **Dog is a Comparator** (with `compare()` implementation).

So it is okay to use it `new Dog()` as `Comparator` for `sort()`. It will sort the elements using the logic you given in `compare()`.